# activeadmin undefined method in relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin

i use rails 4.01 and activeadmin 1.0. and my models are:

```
class City < ActiveRecord::Base
  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :name, use: :slugged
  translates :name, :city_h1, :city_h2, :city_h3, :city_description

  belongs_to :region
  belongs_to :country

  has_many :city_translations


  accepts_nested_attributes_for :city_translations

end


class CityTranslation < ActiveRecord::Base
  extend FriendlyId

  belongs_to :city
  validates_uniqueness_of :locale, :scope => :city_id
end
```

admin/cities.rb

```
ActiveAdmin.register City do
  permit_params :name, :city_h1, :city_h2, :city_h3, :city_description, :region_id, :country_id, :city_translations_attributes,
                city_translations_attributes: [:id, :city_h1, :city_h2, :city_h3, :city_description, :city_id, :locale, :_destroy, :_create, :_update,:_update]


  form :html => { :enctype => "multipart/form-data" }  do |f| 
      f.inputs "Details" do
        f.input :region, :include_blank => false 
        f.input :country, :include_blank => false 

      end



    f.inputs "Vertalingen" do
      f.has_many :city_translations do |g|
        g.inputs "taal" do
          g.input :locale, :as => :radio, :collection => ADDITIONAL_LOCALES, :label => "Taal"
        end
        g.input :name
        g.input :city_h3
        g.input :city_h1
        g.input :city_h2
        g.input :city_h3
        g.input :city_description

      end
    end

   f.actions
    end
end
```

i get the error

undefined method `' for CityTranslation

trace:

```
activemodel (4.0.3) lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb:439:in `method_missing'
activerecord (4.0.3) lib/active_record/attribute_methods.rb:155:in `method_missing'
friendly_id (5.0.4) lib/friendly_id/base.rb:242:in `friendly_id'
activemodel (4.0.3) lib/active_model/validator.rb:151:in `block in validate'
activemodel (4.0.3) lib/active_model/validator.rb:150:in `each'
activemodel (4.0.3) lib/active_model/validator.rb:150:in `validate'
activesupport (4.0.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:283:in `_callback_before_1715'
activesupport (4.0.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:377:in `_run__2897005105520448373__validate__callbacks'
```

i am trying to solve this issue for 2 days but i can't figure out what i am doing wrong.

thanks..remco

Comment: always post the complete backtrace from the exception that you get. if you don't understand what i'm talking about, read this http://nofail.de/2013/10/debugging-rails-applications-in-development/

Comment: yes i know ..but i got the message that their was to many code...but i updated the post with a first part of the trace

Comment: always paste the whole stacktrace unless you know which part is broken.